# Javascript regex .test() "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Just trying to use javascript's regex capabilities with the `.test()` function.

```
  var nameRegex = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,20}$/';

  if(nameRegex.test($('#username').val())) {
      ...
  }
```

The error is on this line `if(nameRegex.test($('#username').val())) {`

Debugger breaks there and says **"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"**. It seems like `.test()` is not defined? Shouldn't it be?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As it currently stands, `nameRegex` isn't a regex but a string and `String` doesn't have `test` functon which is why you are getting that error.

Remove the quotes around your regex. That is the literal form of regex.

```
var nameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,20}$/; //remove the quotes
```

Comment: @Andrew, glad to have helped :)

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks you

Answer (score 10):

Also, you can create the RegExp from a string by the inherent constructor within javascript.

```
var nameRegex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,20}$';
var regex = new RegExp(nameRegex);
...

if(regex.test(stringToTest)) {
    ...
}

...
```

MDN Docs :: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

NOTE: don't provide the initial '/' slashes in the string when creating the regex object... It will add them.